# Why the horizontal arrow does not align vertically?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a style for creating line with or without arrows in pure css, the problem is that i can't align vertically my arrow with vertical-align middle, the horizontal one is working correctly with text-align center;

I've also tried with table-cell display.

Please consider that css is compiled with less.

```css
.box {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 1em;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
}
.linea-h {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 2px dotted dimgray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 0;
}
.linea-h > * {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
}
.linea-h .left-arrow {
  margin-top: -6px;
  border-left: 2px solid dimgray;
  border-bottom: 2px solid dimgray;
  left: 0;
}
.linea-h .right-arrow {
  margin-top: -6px;
  border-right: 2px solid dimgray;
  border-top: 2px solid dimgray;
  right: 0;
}
.linea-v {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-left: 4px dotted dimgray;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 0;
}
.linea-v > * {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
}
.linea-v .top-arrow {
  margin-left: -8px;
  border-left: 4px solid dimgray;
  border-top: 4px solid dimgray;
  top: 0;
}
.linea-v .bottom-arrow {
  margin-left: -8px;
  border-right: 4px solid dimgray;
  border-bottom: 4px solid dimgray;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="linea-h" style="width: 200px">
    <div class="left-arrow"></div>
    <div class="right-arrow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="linea-v" style="height: 200px">
    <div class="top-arrow"></div>
    <div class="bottom-arrow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following properties to vertically align in CSS:

```
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
```

I've made some changes to your `linea-h` class to reflect this.

```css
.box {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 1em;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
}
.linea-h {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 2px dotted dimgray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.linea-h > * {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
}
.linea-h .left-arrow {
  margin-top: -6px;
  border-left: 2px solid dimgray;
  border-bottom: 2px solid dimgray;
  left: 0;
}
.linea-h .right-arrow {
  margin-top: -6px;
  border-right: 2px solid dimgray;
  border-top: 2px solid dimgray;
  right: 0;
}
.linea-v {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-left: 4px dotted dimgray;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 0;
}
.linea-v > * {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
}
.linea-v .top-arrow {
  margin-left: -8px;
  border-left: 4px solid dimgray;
  border-top: 4px solid dimgray;
  top: 0;
}
.linea-v .bottom-arrow {
  margin-left: -8px;
  border-right: 4px solid dimgray;
  border-bottom: 4px solid dimgray;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="linea-h" style="width: 200px">
    <div class="left-arrow"></div>
    <div class="right-arrow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="linea-v" style="height: 200px">
    <div class="top-arrow"></div>
    <div class="bottom-arrow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `float` rule to the `.box` elements
With `display: table-cell` or `display: inline-block` they will still one beside the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use line height in css to align it into middle..Note that you have to use the same value as of height in line-height to place it in center.As you are using less you can add the height to a variable and use it..

```css
.box {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 1em;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
}
.linea-h {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 2px dotted dimgray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 0;
}
.linea-h > * {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
}
.linea-h .left-arrow {
  margin-top: -6px;
  border-left: 2px solid dimgray;
  border-bottom: 2px solid dimgray;
  left: 0;
}
.linea-h .right-arrow {
  margin-top: -6px;
  border-right: 2px solid dimgray;
  border-top: 2px solid dimgray;
  right: 0;
}
.linea-v {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-left: 4px dotted dimgray;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 0;
}
.linea-v > * {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
}
.linea-v .top-arrow {
  margin-left: -8px;
  border-left: 4px solid dimgray;
  border-top: 4px solid dimgray;
  top: 0;
}
.linea-v .bottom-arrow {
  margin-left: -8px;
  border-right: 4px solid dimgray;
  border-bottom: 4px solid dimgray;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="linea-h" style="width: 200px">
    <div class="left-arrow"></div>
    <div class="right-arrow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="linea-v" style="height: 200px">
    <div class="top-arrow"></div>
    <div class="bottom-arrow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the float on the `.box`. I don't see any value in it. Instead, you could make use of the `display: table`, `display: table-cell` properties.

If you have some control over the html, you can add a container over the box elements. You can then apply the following `CSS` on the container :

```
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 14px 5px;
```

Also, the `.box` class needs to have `display: table-cell`. See this below :

```css
.boxContainer {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 14px 5px;
}
.box {
    background-color: lightgray;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-right: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
}
.linea-h {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-top: 2px dotted dimgray;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 0;
}
.linea-h > * {
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
}
.linea-h .left-arrow {
    margin-top: -6px;
    border-left: 2px solid dimgray;
    border-bottom: 2px solid dimgray;
    left: 0;
}
.linea-h .right-arrow {
    margin-top: -6px;
    border-right: 2px solid dimgray;
    border-top: 2px solid dimgray;
    right: 0;
}
.linea-v {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-left: 4px dotted dimgray;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 0;
}
.linea-v > * {
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
}
.linea-v .top-arrow {
    margin-left: -8px;
    border-left: 4px solid dimgray;
    border-top: 4px solid dimgray;
    top: 0;
}
.linea-v .bottom-arrow {
    margin-left: -8px;
    border-right: 4px solid dimgray;
    border-bottom: 4px solid dimgray;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxContainer">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="linea-h" style="width: 200px">
            <div class="left-arrow"></div>
            <div class="right-arrow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="linea-v" style="height: 200px">
            <div class="top-arrow"></div>
            <div class="bottom-arrow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the easiest way to do this is to add line-height:200px; to your box class in css.
I've tested it, should work.

```css
.box {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  margin-right: 1em;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
}
.linea-h {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 2px dotted dimgray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 0;
}
.linea-h > * {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
}
.linea-h .left-arrow {
  margin-top: -6px;
  border-left: 2px solid dimgray;
  border-bottom: 2px solid dimgray;
  left: 0;
}
.linea-h .right-arrow {
  margin-top: -6px;
  border-right: 2px solid dimgray;
  border-top: 2px solid dimgray;
  right: 0;
}
.linea-v {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-left: 4px dotted dimgray;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 0;
}
.linea-v > * {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
}
.linea-v .top-arrow {
  margin-left: -8px;
  border-left: 4px solid dimgray;
  border-top: 4px solid dimgray;
  top: 0;
}
.linea-v .bottom-arrow {
  margin-left: -8px;
  border-right: 4px solid dimgray;
  border-bottom: 4px solid dimgray;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="linea-h" style="width: 200px">
    <div class="left-arrow"></div>
    <div class="right-arrow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="linea-v" style="height: 200px">
    <div class="top-arrow"></div>
    <div class="bottom-arrow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```